# Integrating Multiple Custom Markers with Ionic 2 + Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've searched the web for hours now and can't seem to find the problem to my seemingly, pretty simple issue.

Simply put, the `icon` property of `google.maps.Marker` doesn't seem to do anything when I `ionic serve` the app, despite everything else working out fine.

*In other words, what does Ionic 2 use with the Google Maps Javascript API that allows it to define the icon images for custom markers?*

I'll provide all my relevant code here but I have a feeling that it might not be very helpful for a question like this.
With what I know about Ionic 2, I've been able to integrate Google Maps, it's online/offline states, and some default markers into a page on my app.

BTW, my test image files are located in the same folder as `google-maps.ts` (just doing this for now as I figure out what's happening).

All the code for initializing google maps and creating the addMarker functions are located in this one file (This huge piece of code is placed here just in case, skip the code below to the next snippet to see the most relevant section of it):

**src/providers/google-maps.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Connectivity } from './connectivity';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

/*
  Generated class for the GoogleMaps provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/

declare var google;

@Injectable()

export class GoogleMaps {

mapElement: any;
pleaseConnect: any;
map: any;
mapInitialised: boolean = false;
mapLoaded: any;
mapLoadedObserver: any;
markers: any = [];
apiKey: string;
styles: any;

  constructor(public connectivityService: Connectivity) {

  }

  init(mapElement: any, pleaseConnect: any): Promise<any> {

    this.mapElement = mapElement;
    this.pleaseConnect = pleaseConnect;

    return this.loadGoogleMaps();
  }

  loadGoogleMaps(): Promise<any> {

      return new Promise((resolve) => {

        if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.maps == "undefined") {

          console.log("Google maps Javascript needs to be loaded");
          this.disableMap();

          if(this.connectivityService.isOnline()) {

            window['mapInit'] = () => {

              this.initMap().then(() => {
                resolve(true);
              });

              this.enableMap();
            }

            let script = document.createElement("script");
            script.id = "googleMaps";

            if(this.apiKey) {
              script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=' + this.apiKey 
                + '&callback=mapInit';
            } else {
              script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=mapInit';
            }

            document.body.appendChild(script);
          }
        }
        else {
          if(this.connectivityService.isOnline()) {
            this.initMap();
            this.enableMap();
          } else {
            this.disableMap();
          }
        }

        this.addConnectivityListeners();
      })
  }

  initMap(): Promise<any> {

    this.mapInitialised = true;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
         //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,    -Doesn't seem necessary anymore
          styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }

  disableMap(): void {

    if(this.pleaseConnect) {
      this.pleaseConnect.style.display = "block";
    }

  }

  enableMap(): void {

    if(this.pleaseConnect) {
      this.pleaseConnect.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  addConnectivityListeners(): void {

    document.addEventListener('online', () => {

      console.log("online");

      setTimeout(() => {

        if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.maps == "undefined") {
          this.loadGoogleMaps();
        }
        else {
          if(!this.mapInitialised) {
            this.initMap();
          }

          this.enableMap();
        }

      },2000);
    }, false);
  }

//Setting up custom Google Maps markers

//iconBase: any = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/'; -Probably not necessary


icons: any = {
  partner: {
    icon: 'partner.png'
  },
  boughtFrom: {
    icon: 'boughtFrom.png'
  }
}

  addMarker(lat: number, lng: number, feature: any): void {

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng,
      icon: this.icons[feature].icon
    });

    this.markers.push(marker);

  }

}
```

The part that isn't working for me is the "icon" assignment in that last "addMarker()" function:

```
  addMarker(lat: number, lng: number, feature: any): void {

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng,
      icon: this.icons[feature].icon    //Doesn't do anything
    });

    this.markers.push(marker);

  }
```

Currently I'm attempting to also call different types of markers for different locations, but even if I simply replace it with `partners.png` or `{ url: 'partners.img' }`, it still doesn't recognize anything.

In case this matters, these are also the two test markers I'm using that appear in default style on the map:

**src/assets/data/locations.json**

```
{
    "locations": [

        {
            "latitude": 40.79567309999999,
            "longitude": -73.97358559999998,
            "type": "partner"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 40.8107211,
            "longitude": -73.95413259999998,
            "type": "boughtFrom"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'll also include the map page that integrates all this info:

**src/pages/home.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../../providers/google-maps';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('pleaseConnect') pleaseConnect: ElementRef;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public maps: GoogleMaps, 
              public Platform: Platform, public locations: Locations) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.Platform.ready().then(() => {

      let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);
      let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load();

      Promise.all([
        mapLoaded,
        locationsLoaded
      ]).then((result) => {

        let locations = result[1];

        for(let location of locations) {
          this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude, location.type);
        }
      })
  });
  }

}
```

Thank you for your time!

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, what does Ionic 2 use with the Google Maps Javascript API that allows it to define the icon images for custom markers?

Nothing. Ionic has no responsibility for this whatsoever.

> BTW, my test image files are located in the same folder as google-maps.ts (just doing this for now as I figure out what's happening).

This is the issue. The build process takes typescript files from a place and compiles them in to a single file. In to build www/build/main.js.

These images are not there with the main.js
Move your images to assets folder and give the proper path.

For example:

```
  icon: 'assets/icon1.png'
```

Comment: Wow i feel so silly, I thought i tried that but it seems like I literally just typed in the syntax wrong last time.

It works great now :) thank you very much misha!